# Downloading particular file from S3 bucket

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-s3

I have ios project written in swift 2.3 that is integrated with AWS by following the instructions from AWS mobile hub integration page. On the page that explains about downloading file from s3 bucket, it provides a function, and that function takes AWSContent type parameter. I'd like to use that function to download a particular file from S3 bucket. I tried using contentWithKey member of AWSUserFileManager with my file name and path but getting "found nil while unwrapping optional value" error. Could anyone point me to the right direction? Thanks.

```
private var manager: AWSUserFileManager!
class S3Access: NSObject {


  func setupS3Acess() {
    let x = manager.contentWithKey("public/GMG.csv")
    downloadContent(x, pinOnCompletion: false)
  }

  // This code is from Amazon MobileHub integration page
  private func downloadContent(content: AWSContent, pinOnCompletion: Bool) {
    content.downloadWithDownloadType(
        .IfNewerExists,
        pinOnCompletion: pinOnCompletion,
        progressBlock: {[weak self](content: AWSContent?, progress: NSProgress?) -> Void in
            guard self != nil else { return }
            /* Show progress in UI. */
        },
        completionHandler: {[weak self](content: AWSContent?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            guard self != nil else { return }
            if let error = error {
                print("Failed to download a content from a server. \(error)")
                return
            }
            print("Object download complete.")
        })
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit. I need to assign manager variable with default user file manager like "manager = AWSUserFileManager.defaultUserFileManager()". I'm just posting this for dev like myself who already integrated with AWS libraries to the project and does not require additional authentication setup.

```
private var manager: AWSUserFileManager!
class S3Access: NSObject {


  func setupS3Acess() {
     manager = AWSUserFileManager.defaultUserFileManager()
    let x = manager.contentWithKey("public/GMG.csv")
    downloadContent(x, pinOnCompletion: false)
  }

  // This code is from Amazon MobileHub integration page
  private func downloadContent(content: AWSContent, pinOnCompletion: Bool) {
    content.downloadWithDownloadType(
        .IfNewerExists,
        pinOnCompletion: pinOnCompletion,
        progressBlock: {[weak self](content: AWSContent?, progress: NSProgress?) -> Void in
            guard self != nil else { return }
            /* Show progress in UI. */
        },
        completionHandler: {[weak self](content: AWSContent?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            guard self != nil else { return }
            if let error = error {
                print("Failed to download a content from a server. \(error)")
                return
            }
            print("Object download complete.")
        })
}

}
```